# MikroORM mongo's nested population returns unnecessary data

Tags: mongodb, mikro-orm

T have a nested structure:

- **RequestEntity** has one *requester* (**UserEntity**), one *department* (**DepartmentEntity**)
- **UserEntity** has one *department* (**DepartmentEntity**)
  Note that all entities have one *created* and one *modified* (**UserEntity**)

Query:

```
em.find(RequestEntity, {}, { populate: ['requester.department', 'department']})
```

The returned results include the fields I don't want to populate: *created*, *modified*. Moreover, **UserEntity** has populated *department*, *department* has populated *created* (**UserEntity**). That repeatedly makes 1 returned record very large, maybe up to 10Mb.

Can someone give me a solution please? Sorry my English is not good so I can't explain the problem very clearly.

Comment: You can mark any property as `lazy: true`, that way it wont be automatically selected. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/defining-entities#lazy-scalar-properties

Comment: Alternatively you can use partial loading and specify only what you want to select when calling `em.find`: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager#fetching-partial-entities